# Remove three last lines from spool file using wc -l and sed

Tags: bash, unix, sed, sql-loader, wc

I am facing an issue that I have File that every time have different row count and it ends with sqlldr output that shows amount of rows exported to file

```
40968 rows selected.
```

Since this file will be picked up by next process I want to get rid of this additional text.
So I came up with idea like this:

```
# Remove exported record count from end of file
remove_count=$(( $(wc -l < ${output_dir}/file.dat)-3+1 ))
echo "Removing extra lines from spooled file"
sed '$remove_count, $ d' file.dat >> file.dat
```

The problem is that it seems that `sed` cannot use variable as amount of lines after which it should start deleting. I could not find better solution.
Is there something I can do better or anyone sees mistake?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use double quotes in last `sed` command

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need such a complicated solution; `head` can do this:

```
$ echo -e 'first\nsecond\nthird\nfourth' | head -n-3
first
```

See the manual:

```
       -n, --lines=[-]NUM
              print the first NUM lines instead of  the  first  10;  with  the
              leading '-', print all but the last NUM lines of each file
```

Comment: Excellent answer, learning new thing every day.

Answer (score 0):

`sed` can include variables expansion.

It is a matter of correct `bash` quoting.

`'` prevents any `bash` expansion in string.

`"` allow all `bash` expansion in string.

#### Suggesting to try:

```
# Remove exported record count from end of file
remove_count=$(( $(wc -l < ${output_dir}/file.dat)-3+1 ))
echo "Removing extra lines from spooled file"
sed -i "$remove_count, \$ d" file.dat
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '1N;N;$d;P;D' file
```

This will delete the last 3 lines of a file.

A programmatic version would be:

```
sed ':a;N;s/[^\n]*/&/3;Ta;d$;P;D' file
```

Where `3` can be any number of lines from the end of the file.